# orthogonality-like in vector normed space

Tags: normed-spaces, orthogonality

Given a normed real vector space $V$, and a vector $x\ne 0$, there exists a vector $y\ne 0$ such that $\|x+y\|=\|x-y\|$?

I know that it exists if the norm is induced by a scalar product (in particular, it's equivalent to say that $y$ is orthogonal to $x$), but in a general context?

More in particular, this problem arises when you consider the space of continuous functions, since the infinity norm isn't induced by a scalar product. So, if $V$ is a subspace of the continuous functions on a limited interval can we say something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, assuming that the dimension is $\geq2$.

Define$$f:V\to\mathbb{R},\quad y\mapsto\|x+y\|-\|x-y\|.$$The function $f$ is clearly continuous. Pick any $0\neq y_0\in V$. If $f(y_0)=0$, we're good. Otherwise, take some path $\gamma:[0,1]\to V$ connecting $y_0$ with $-y_0$, without passing through $0$. Since $f(\gamma(0))$ and $f(\gamma(1))$ have opposite signs, there must be some $t\in(0,1)$ with $f(\gamma(t))=0$.